# Half bridge and full bridge control rectifier

Tags: rectifier, scr, bridge-rectifier

Why do we use 2 SCRs and 2 diodes in a half bridge control rectifier and 4 SCRs in a full bridge control

[image: half bridge converter]

The image above shows a half bridge control rectifier

Full bridge control rectifier replaces diodes with SCRs

Comment: Have you got a schematic that you can post into the question?

Comment: Yes. I'll add the circuits and the output graphs

Comment: Due to lack of reputation, I cannot post more than 2 links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is whether you want 2 quadrant or single quadrant control, with half SCRs and half diodes you get only 1QD, no regenerative energy can be transfered back.
link: http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/21.pdf

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: Which part do you not understand? PS. I don't see not even one point 2,3 or 6, so I can't know what your question is.

Comment: The quadrant parts. How does using 2 diodes and 2 SCRs, restrict us to 2 quadrants? How does using 4 SCRs allow operation in 4 quadrants?

Comment: I'm sorry about the poor image quality